# How do I keep my mac from going into sleep mode?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have tried setting the energy saver setting sleep to never. I tried both Caffeine and NoSleep apps. I've tried setting pmset sleep to 0. I read somewhere that it might be the lid sensor which is on the ribbon cable for the battery light indicator, so I disconnected it but it would still go to sleep. I've also tried resetting the SMC, and it made no difference. Not sure what is wrong. I'm running 10.9.3 on a Macbook Pro mid 2009.

Update: http://pastebin.com/7Q3aVZam Power Management logs

Comment: Are you trying to prevent sleep after inactivity or sleep when closing the lid of your MacBook Pro?

Comment: Well technically neither, my mac just goes to sleep on its own whilst I'm working. So I'd at least like to try and fix the sleep "symptom" before trying to find out what the cause is

Comment: Please can you expand your answer to include more about the symptoms; it is not clear what behaviour you are seeing. Also try `pmset -g everything > ~/Desktop/pm.txt` to create a dump of power management logs and other useful power information. There are likely clues in there to help those answering this question.

Comment: The fans also behave strangely, most of the time at full speed but sometimes at 223rpm!. When I changed the peseta sleep to 0 the mac rebooted on its own, however this only happened twice and hasn't happened again. I'll update the question with the a pastebin link to the logs. Thanks a lot for your help and advice btw.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the System Management Controller (SMC)? This controller is responsible for the fans and power management at a hardware level; http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

Comment: Oh yea sorry, should've mentioned I tried that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help Graham, but I decided to take a look at my logic board and found some places that had been corroded. I removed my logic board and gave it a good clean with isopropyl alcohol and a toothbrush and for now my mac has stopped going to sleep on its own, also fans are back to normal.